# Downloading file conditionally with timestamp, like curl -z

Tags: ios, curl, download, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I'm looking for the equivalent of a curl -z SOME_DATE SOME_URL using NSURLRequest of AFNetworking.  I basically want to download a file from a url according to it's timestamp on the server.

(or something like curl -z local.file remote.file, that automatically only downloads remote.file if it was last modified later than local.file was)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking uses NSURLRequest to make requests; so this behavior will be the same regardless of which you choose.

Set your NSURLRequest's `cachePolicy` property to [`NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy) and the behavior will be done for you according to the Cache-Control headers sent down by the server.  In most cases, it does this by adding the `If-Modified-Since` header to your request.